# Parsing HTML with Regular Expressions?

Tags: java, regex

I've been trying to gather information using regular expressions:

```
Pattern hp = Pattern.compile("<small>.....</small>"); 
            Matcher mp = hp.matcher(code);
            while (mp.find()) {
                    String grupoHORARIO = mp.group();        
            System.out.println(grupoHORARIO);         }
```

When I run the program, instead of showing me:

```
RESULT1
RESULT2
RESULT3
```

It shows this:

```
<small>RESULT1</small>
<small>RESULT2</small>
```

As you see, it shows the opening and closing "small" tags before and after the word I am looking for.
What I need is just the word, without the "small" tags around it.

Comment: [Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML; use an HTML or XML parser.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Comment: [You forgot this link.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2030691)

Comment: Canonical question: *[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[USING REGEX TO PARSE HTML IS BAD.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2030691)

Again, [using RegEx to parse HTML is bad.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2030691)

That being said...  In answer to your question, the problem is how you're using the Regular Expression.  The only code of yours I would change is what is inside the `Pattern.compile()` method.  The [way you're currently doing it](http://fiddle.re/z4f1a), (click on the Java button to view the results), you will only match when there is `<small>`, then 5 characters, then `</small>`.  This match includes the start and end tags.

If what you want is to only match the middle parts, then you can try [using RegEx lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).  [The way I did it is:](http://fiddle.re/u4k1a) `(?<=<small>).*(?=</small>)`.  Into parts:

`.*` - Any number of characters.

`.*(?=</small>)` - Any number of characters that are followed by `</small>`.

`(?<=<small>).*(?=</small>)` - Any number of characters that are preceded by `<small>` and followed by `</small>`.

If you don't want to have it match any character, then replace the `.*` with whatever you do want to find (for example, `.....` or `{5}.` will match 5 characters).

Comment: That was really helpful! And, What can I do in cases when I just want to get any number of characters that are preceeded by the code below ?
When I try to do that, it throws the following: "Invalid regular expression: Look behind-group does not have an obvious maximum length.

Comment: The regullar expression that throws me the exception is this:
`(?<=<span class=\"itemName\">.*`

Comment: In your example, you forgot the closing paren.  It should be `(?<=<span class=\"itemName\">).*`

Comment: -1 for `USING REGEX TO PARSE HTML IS BAD`. +1 for a good answer despite that.

Comment: I read in so many websites that using regex to parse html is not right. But that's the only way I know for now

Comment: @SebaPaz: Many people on SO want you to use an XML parser whenever you have to process any text that resembles XML. See [java XML parsing](http://www.google.co.nz/search?q=java+XML+parsing) (Google search)

Comment: @AdrianPronk is right, XML parsers are the way to go.  Hence the first few lines of my answer.  Shame, though, that people -1 a completely useful answer, and +1 "Go Away, your approach is wrong" answers.

Comment: Yes, it is. I have not enough reputation yet to +1 your answer, but it was totally helpful to me.

Comment: Hopefully people seeing this answer will think two things.  1: Regex is indeed powerful, and can do a lot of parsing successfully.  2: Don't use it in HTML.